# PHP mySQL - replace some string inside string

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, replace

i want to replace ALL comma `,` into `,<space>` in all address table in my mysql table.

For example,

```
+----------------+----------------+
| Name           | Address        |
+----------------+----------------+
| Someone name   | A1,Street Name |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Into

```
+----------------+----------------+
| Name           | Address        |
+----------------+----------------+
| Someone name   | A1, Street Name|
+----------------+----------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tabl SET Address = REPLACE(Address, ',', ', ')
```

Back up your table before trying it out!

You can read more about replace function here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: @apis17, do realize that the above will make `A1,<space>Street Name` -> `A1,<space><space>Street Name` which might not be ideal (might then require you to scan for all the double spaces and replace them with single spaces)

Comment: @Unreason, It would be better to first replace commas with some strange marker (like @@#!@#$!) then replace all occurrences of marker plus space with comma and space, and then do the same with remaining markers.

Comment: @Kamil, any special value algorithm is evil :) I left it open for the OP to comment if it is even an issue (maybe there are no ,<space> in the addresses, or having ,<space><space> is not an issue). If it needs to be addressed I then one approach is similar to what you are suggesting, but does not use special/strange marker; instead it would `REPLACE(Address, ', ', ',')` first and after that `REPLACE(Address, ',', ', ')`. This would achieve the same in 2 queries, your suggestion would do it in 3. Your suggestion would update 2*n records (where n is the number of records with comma in them).

Comment: The shrink-expand approach would not need to update 2*n records, but only at most 2*n records. It would not solve the problem of ',<space><space>'. One more note - mysql checks if the new value is equal to old value in UPDATE and skips I/O if it is, but some DBMS don't and in those cases using WHERE conditions might help (in some cases for mysql it is faster too, depending on selectivity and indexes).

Comment: @Unreason - I like your shrink/expand approach very much. It's way better than my magic marker idea.

Comment: @Kamil, nevermind don't need double spaces problem here. if this happen i will do 2 query to complete task. if there are any simplest code, i want to bookmark here in case need further repair next time.
@Unreason, marked 1 great comment for your post. :)